# ext js accordion

Tags: extjs, accordion

http://www.myethiopia.org/QuickLinks/accordion.html
Please check this link in IE.  I did not have time to figure out why it is not working in Firefox.   I am trying to click on a link on the left column and have the page open in the center.
If you click on Weather Station and Oromiya Station, the title opens up fine but the link does not even open.  Line No.325  under var menu1, look at the first item for the code. What am I doing wrong?
Second question. I want a round bulltein or outline type of thing (not sure what to  call it) to the left of the Oromiya station. HOw can I do that?
Checkbox is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the centerpanel html you can use the update() function.

In this small example I've added an 'id' to the center panel and then in the handler function for the menu item used this code to show an update.

```
var centerRegion = Ext.getCmp('centerpanel');                             
centerRegion.update('<iframe src="http://www.myethiopia.org/QuickLinks/Weather/EthiopiaWeatherStations/Amharastations.html" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>');
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but it looks like you want to load the grid into the centerpanel, you can do that directly without having to load in a separate html page.